# Loop with socket function doesn't work - WebSocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a socket endpoint, that I connect to and send a message to get a user.
I used this code to do it :

```
import generateConnection from './generate-connection';

export async function fetchUser(id: number) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    const connection = generateConnection();
    connection.onopen = () => {
      connection.send(
        JSON.stringify(
          '{"msg":"connect","version":"1","support":["1","pre2","pre1"]}',
        ),
      );
      connection.send(
        JSON.stringify(
          `{"msg":"method","id":"1","method":"Users.getUser","params":[${id}]}`,
        ),
      );
      console.log('Connected');
    };
    connection.on('message', async (event) => {
      const data = event.toString();
      if (data[0] == 'a') {
        const a = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data.substring(1))[0]);
        if (a.msg == 'result') {
          if ('error' in a) {
            console.log('Error' + a.error.msg);
            return null;
          } else {
            resolve(a.result);
          }
        }
      }
    });
    connection.on('error', function (error) {
      console.log('Connection Error: ' + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function () {
      console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
    });
  });
}

const fetchAllUsers = async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const user: any = await fetchUser(i);
    console.log(user.name);
  }
};
fetchAllUsers();
```

I get the following result :

```
Connected
Jack
```

It just give me the first user and it stop on the second.

I have no control over the socket and I want to be able to fetch all 5000 users each day to be synced.

I'm Using WebSocket for this problem.

If you have any proposition other than this method, I'm all ears :D

To explain more :

1 - I want to open a connection

2 - Send a message

3 - get Result

4 - Add to Array or db

5 - When finished, close the connection.

6 - repeat

Comment: Why would you create a new connection for each of the 5000 users you want to retrieve?  Create one connection, set up one set of message handlers on that one connection and then send 5000 requests over that one connection.  Then, close the connection when you're done with it.

Comment: My assumption is that `generateConnection` always connect to the same port. This + the fact that you don't seem to close the connection after you get your data means that the next time you try to open a connection, onopen will not be triggered. As such you never send your message > never get the response > never resolve the promise > your code is blocked in the second iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you close the connection every time? An open connection allows you to send many messages. But maybe it is easier to:

```
connection.close()

// right before:
resolve(a.result);
```

If that didn't work maybe it's time to send more then one request per connection. Try this (I'm a little rusty with promises so I hope you get the idea and improve it)

```js
import generateConnection from './generate-connection';

export async function fetchAllUsers() {
  var total = 100;
  var returned = 0;
  var all_results = [];

  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    const connection = generateConnection();
    connection.onopen = () => {
      connection.send(
        JSON.stringify(
          '{"msg":"connect","version":"1","support":["1","pre2","pre1"]}',
        ),
      );

      for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        connection.send(
          JSON.stringify(
            `{"msg":"method","id":"1","method":"Users.getUser","params":[${i}]}`,
          ),
        );
      }

      console.log('Connected');
    };
    connection.on('message', async(event) => {
      const data = event.toString();
      if (data[0] == 'a') {
        const a = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data.substring(1))[0]);
        if (a.msg == 'result') {
          if ('error' in a) {
            console.log('Error' + a.error.msg);
            return null;
          } else {
            console.log(a.result.name);
            all_results.push(a.result);

            returned++;

            if (returned == total) {
              resolve(all_results);
            }

          }
        }
      }
    });
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
      console.log('Connection Error: ' + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function() {
      console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
    });
  });
}


fetchAllUsers();
```

Comment: I tried with opening a connection and closing it when I end the loop, but it keeps giving me only one user :/ I even tried   :  return Promise.all(
    Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i + 1).map((id) => fetchUser(id)),
  );